# SetInterval not working in p5.js (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, setinterval, p5.js

In *p5.js* when I use `setInterval()` it is sending an error saying `setInterval not defined`. I’ve checked if I typed it wrong but it’s exactly what I typed and I know you can use it in *p5.js* because I’ve seen other people do it. Why do I get that error? I only have 5-7 months of experience by the way.

Comment: “setIntrval not defined” is not a type, right?

Also, did you try window.setInterval()?

Comment: Thanks @Perspectivus